# Power consumption during BLE connection establishing: Which role (peripheral/central) is more efficient?

Tags: logging, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to collect measurement data over BLE from a number of battery powered sensors into a wall-powered logger. The measurement intervals are of the order of minutes. I need guaranteed data delivery, so the sensors cannot send the data in advertisement packets, instead I need to establish a connection such that data transfer can be acknowledged. When connections are established for short uses, which role is more power efficient, the central or the peripheral? I see two network configurations:

1. Sensors as peripherals, logger as central: The sensors only advertise when they have new data, the logger then connects and pulls the data.
2. Sensors as centrals, logger as peripheral: The logger continuously advertises. When the sensors have new data, they connect to the logger and push the data.

Which of these two variants would conserve more power on the sensors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The battery powered devices should be peripherals. The reason is that scanning consumes a lot of energy since it needs to keep the radio on to be able to receive an advertisement packet. When you advertise, you turn on the radio, transmit the packet, wait "T_IFS" (inter frame space which is 150 microseconds), then listen for a very short time for a CONNECT_IND packet. The packet must be sent in a window of 4 microseconds, otherwise the advertiser turns the radio off.

You should also have the wall powered central scanning with a scan window equal to the scan interval (i.e. scans 100% of the time) so you will catch all advertisement packets. With a scan window smaller than the scan interval, the advertiser might need to advertise many packets before the scanner detects it, which consumes more power.